# Is there a way to configure rendering depth in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let's say I've got my domain objects laid out so the XML looks like this:

```
<account id="1">
  <name>Dan</name>
  <friends>
    <friend id="2">
      <name>RJ</name>
    </friend>
    <friend id="3">
      <name>George</name>
    </friend>
  </friends>
</account>
```

My domain object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Account {
    @XmlAttribute
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "friends")
    @XmlElement(name = "friend")
    public List<Account> friends;
}
```

Is there an easy way to configure JAXB to render only to a depth of 2? Meaning, I'd like my XML to look like this:

```
<account id="1">
    <name>Dan</name>
    <friends>
        <friend id="2" />
        <friend id="3" />
    </friends>
</account>
```

Comment: Not with JAXB, no. You should be able to pipe the output of JAXB into some other XML-manipulation process which does that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an [XmlJavaTypeAdapter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html).

Change Account as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Account {
    @XmlAttribute
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "friends")
    @XmlElement(name = "friend")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( value = AccountAdapter.class )
    public List<Account> friends;
}
```

AccountAdapter.java:

```
public class AccountAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AccountRef, Account>
{
    @Override
    public AccountRef marshal(Account v) throws Exception 
    {   
        AccountRef ref = new AccountRef();
        ref.id = v.id;
        return ref;
    }

    @Override
    public Account unmarshal(AccountRef v) throws Exception 
    {
        // Implement if you need to deserialize
    }
}
```

AccountRef.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AccountRef 
{ 
    @XmlAttribute
    public Long id;
}
```

Comment: Have you teted this? I'm fairly sure this won't work, `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` can only handle scalar string values, not whole XML elements, even if the class signature suggests otherwise.

Comment: @skaffman - yes I've tested it (though I noticed that I forgot to included the definition of AccountRef - I've updated my answer).  The key is that XMLJavaTypeAdapter allows you to not only serialize a class that JAXB doesn't know about but also change how a class is serialized on a per-field basis.  Here I'm creating a new class which serializes just the id field of an Account.